# How to validate HTML <input> multiple attribute in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have an HTML form where users can upload multiple images. I'm looking for the solution to validate images before they are uploaded. I use following HTML tag:

```
<input id="images" multiple="multiple" name="images[]" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

For the validation I made *RealEstateValidation* request class. In the validation class I use rules method to define validation rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
              'area'=>'required',
              'number_of_rooms'=>'required',                 
              'address'=>'required'
        ];
    }
```

What should I add into the rules to validate images? For example I added `'images' => 'array|image|max:1000'` line but it did not work? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do a small change:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
          'area'=>'required',
          'number_of_rooms'=>'required',                 
          'address'=>'required'
          'images.*'=>'required|image'

    ];
}
```

Comment: you can get error like this <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('images.0') }}</span>